# MySQL : Combinging Aggregate function with Date Time function in a join

Tags: mysql, datetime, join, group-by

Suppose I have two tables, one for probes and one for alien encounters that each probe makes..

```
 PROBE
 id           probe_launch_date
 --------     -----------------
 1            12/03/2214
 2            02/06/2215
 3            07/09/2215

ENCOUNTER
id              encounter_species  encounter_date     probe_id
 -----------     ----------------   --------------     --------
 1                Klingons           01/06/2215         1
 2                Romulans           09/15/2215         2
 3                Vulcans            11/15/2215         2
```

I would like to see how many alien encounters each probe made since its launch date and I want the data grouped by the week since probe launch. So for example for probe 2 the result set might look like

```
  week  encounter
  ----  --------
  31     1
  40     1
```

Here is my first crack the SQL..

```
 SELECT WEEK(a.probe_launch_date) as launch_week, b.COUNT(*) 
  as num_of_encounters FROM probe a, encounter b  
  where a.id = b.probe_id and a.id = 2 GROUP BY  WEEK(a.probe_launch_date)
```

Of course this didn't work. How can I fix or re-write it?

Comment: week() is a mysql function encounter id = 1 will return a 1.

Comment: b.COUNT( * )  is bad ==> COUNT(b.* )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** based on feedback in comments:

The driving table should really be your `encounter` table, as those are the weeks you are interested in.

Use the [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function to calculate the number of days between the launch date and encounter date, then divide by 7 and [ROUND](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) to get weeks.

```
SELECT ROUND(DATEDIFF(e.encounter_date, p.probe_launch_date) / 7, 0) AS week, 
        COUNT(*) AS number_of_encounters
    FROM encounter e
        INNER JOIN probe p
            ON e.probe_id = p.probe_id
    WHERE e.probe_id = 2
    GROUP BY ROUND(DATEDIFF(e.encounter_date, p.probe_launch_date) / 7, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, but I really need to group the data by the number of weeks since launch, is that possible? To have the result set look like my example?

Comment: @AbuMariam I've edited my answer based on your feedback.